# Element intersection between two matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, apply

This probably has an easy solution, but I can still not find one. I have two matrices, one of size M1 = (4, 2000000), and the other, M2=(4,209). I want to find the length of elements intersection between each column of M2 to all columns of M1.

For one column in M2 I do:

```
res <- apply(M1, 2, function(x) length(intersect(tmp, x)))
```

where tmp is the first column of M2.

This takes about 30 seconds. To speed up the calculation for all columns of M2, I do foreach:

```
list <- foreach(k=1:ncol(M2)) %dopar% {

    tmp <- M2[,k]
    res <- apply(M1, 2, function(x) length(intersect(tmp, x)))
}
```

This takes about 20 minutes.

Is there a way to avoid this foreach loop with an apply function?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems `tcrossprod(table(col(M1), M1) > 0L, table(col(M2), M2) > 0L)` is similar to what you're doing.Since you don't care about the number of occurences, `table(col(M1), M1) > 0L` could be replaced with a more efficient `replace(matrix(0L, ncol(M1), max(M1)), cbind(rep(1:ncol(M1), each = nrow(M1)), c(M1)), 1L)` or, even, consider using a sparse matrix considering the size of your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having data:

```
set.seed(991)
M1 = matrix(sample(5, 50, TRUE), 5)
M2 = matrix(sample(5, 25, TRUE), 5)
```

your solution returns:

```
op = sapply(1:ncol(M2), 
            function(k) apply(M1, 2, function(x) length(intersect(M2[, k], x))))
op 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    3    1    3    2    3
# [2,]    3    2    3    3    4
# [3,]    2    2    2    2    3
# [4,]    2    3    3    2    3
# [5,]    2    2    3    1    2
# [6,]    2    2    2    2    3
# [7,]    2    3    3    2    3
# [8,]    2    2    3    3    3
# [9,]    2    2    3    3    3
#[10,]    1    3    2    1    2
```

which is what

```
ans1 = tcrossprod(table(col(M1), M1) > 0L, table(col(M2), M2) > 0L)
```

returns.

```
all.equal(op, ans1, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Since we don't need the number of occurences, we could replace the expensive calls to `table` with simple matrix manipulations:

```
m1 = matrix(0L, ncol(M1), max(M1))
m1[cbind(rep(1:ncol(M1), each = nrow(M1)), c(M1))] = 1L

m2 = matrix(0L, ncol(M2), max(M2))
m2[cbind(rep(1:ncol(M2), each = nrow(M2)), c(M2))] = 1L
ans2 = tcrossprod(m1, m2)

all.equal(op, ans2)
#[1] TRUE
```

For your case, it seems more suitable to start by making sparse tabulations, if there is a chance to avoid memory contraints:

```
library(Matrix)
sm1 = sparseMatrix(x = 1L, 
                   i = rep(1:ncol(M1), each = nrow(M1)), 
                   j = M1, 
                   use.last.ij = TRUE)
sm2 = sparseMatrix(x = 1L, 
                   i = rep(1:ncol(M2), each = nrow(M2)), 
                   j = M2,
                   use.last.ij = TRUE)
ans3 = tcrossprod(sm1, sm2)

all.equal(op, as.matrix(ans3), check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Now add benchmarks so everyone will be able to appreciate better your awesome solution :P

Comment: @DavidArenburg : I can't avoid the fear that the  `ncol(M1) * length(unique.default(M1))` tabulation might bring a `cannot allocate memory` comment that will turn a benchmark into a christmas snowflake... :-)

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's he main issue with vectorized solutions- they aren't memory efficient compared to simple loops.

Comment: Well, @alexis_laz, I am impressed by your tcrossprod solution! 12 seconds!! Amazing! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Given your matrix dimensions, you could do this which should be faster:

```
apply(m2, 2, function(x) colSums(m1==x[1] | m1==x[2] | m1==x[3] | m1==x[4]))
```

For example, suppose:

```
m1 

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    6    4
[2,]    9    8   11
[3,]   10    1   12
[4,]    2    5    7

m2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    1    5
[4,]    8    4
```

Then, it will give you:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    0
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    0    2
```

---

**Update about time efficiency**

So to summarize, as the OP has mentioned in the comments,

- The naive `for` solution takes about `20 mins`
- My solution takes about `36 secs`
- That of @alexis_laz about `12 secs`

for doing the same job.

Comment: Thanks @989! I also tried your solution on my dataset, given a solution in 36 seconds. Thank you!

Comment: @Andres Good to know. So its much faster than the naive `for` solution. Better to thank a solution by an up vote ;)